# DataFrame to list of list without change in data type of values

Tags: python, pandas

`df.values.to_list()` or `list(df.values)` converts dataframe to list of lists, but the integer values are converted to float values

DataFrame is,

```
   HSCode  value  year
0       2   0.18  2018
1       3   0.00  2018
2       4  12.48  2018
3       6   0.00  2018
4       7   1.89  2018
```

output required is

```
[[2,0.18,2018],[3,0.00,2018]..]
```

But `df.values.tolist()` gives

```
[[2.0,0.18,2018.0],...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `itertuples`

```
list(map(list, df.itertuples(index=False)))

[[2, 0.18, 2018],
 [3, 0.0, 2018],
 [4, 12.48, 2018],
 [6, 0.0, 2018],
 [7, 1.89, 2018]]
```

---

#### A little more terse

And far less readable

```
[*map(list, zip(*map(df.get, df)))]

[[2, 0.18, 2018],
 [3, 0.0, 2018],
 [4, 12.48, 2018],
 [6, 0.0, 2018],
 [7, 1.89, 2018]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the intermediate `numpy` records array to conserve datatypes, and then if you must, convert to a list.

This approach, while being quite fast, will leave you with a list of tuples, as opposed to a list of lists.

---

```
df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
```

```
[(2, 0.18, 2018),
 (3, 0.0, 2018),
 (4, 12.48, 2018),
 (6, 0.0, 2018),
 (7, 1.89, 2018)]
```

Comment: This still may be quicker `[*zip(*map(df.get, df))]`

Comment: Agreed, `to_records` won't provide a performance gain over that unless the number of columns is quite high.

Comment: Nope.  Over a longer dataframe, it is ~ 2 x faster.  Over wider data... still faster.

Comment: I'll probably use `to_records` more often because of this.

Comment: I am seeing `df.get` perform better until about 1000x1000, then it seems to change.  On floats, `df.get` performs better for a bit longer, up until about 3000.  Either way, the `tolist` is what takes up the majority of the time

Comment: When I'm motivated, I'll investigate further.